# Unit test repositories with XML as datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I'm a unit-testing noob and struggling to find a good way to test my repositories. I have created a CustomConfigurationManager that loads my `Custom.Config` values. But cannot figure out how to test them.

My questions are

1. How do I test the code inside `GetUserById()`
2. How do I test my `CustomConfigurationManager()`

This is my repository I'm trying to test:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User GetUserById(string id)
    {
        return CustomConfigurationManager.CustomConfig.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
    }
}


public class CustomConfigurationManager
{
    public static Configs CustomConfig
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomConfigLoader.LoadConfig<Configs>();
        }
    }
}

internal sealed class ConfigLoader
{
    public static T LoadConfig<T>() where T : class
    {
        ...

        return LoadFromXML<T>();
    }
}
```

And the XML

```
 <users>
    <user id="Foo" name="Bar" ... />
    ...
</users>
```

The code I pasted is modified and is not the real code. It's only an example.

Comment: Have you considered relying on Integration Testing to prove that your repositories work?  You can create a mock database to test your repository methods, but you still need to test them with a real database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure many will point out that in a precise sense, if you're reading a file, it isn't a unit test. Really, you should be testing something like that in a more loose manner, or find a way to fake it.

A tip that should help you considerably:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public Configs CustomConfig {get;set;}
    public User GetUserById(string id)
    {
        return CustomConfig.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
    }
}
```

The idea is that by injecting it (perhaps only in the constructor) you can test it without reading from a file. This is called DI (Dependency Injection) and is generally best done with an interface.

Your CustomConfigurationManager is difficult to test because it calls another static method in a property; you can probably just not use it. It's extra complexity which hides details but hides *dependencies* as well, which you never want to do.

You can't really test the ConfigLoader without InternalsVisibleTo, but I consider that bad practice as well. Does this class *need* to be sealed?

Try to focus your design around making methods work without assuming a specific implementation where possible. If you find yourself passing in too many things, you probably need a new class. If you find yourself doing too many things at once, you probably need more methods.

Comment: I have similar question to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495025/how-to-convey-xml-datasource-to-repository-pattern-best-practises I would be thankful for some ideas in that matter